# pytest ordered plugin doesn't work with combination of multiple files

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-django

Hi I am using "http://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.org/en/develop/" and order works fine when I use decorators as below,

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.run(order=3)
def test_three():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def test_four():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
def test_two():
    assert True
```

Now say I have two files test_example1.py and 2nd file as test_example2.py

In this case If I use this ordering then order=1 from file1 and file2 gets executed first and then it starts executing order=2 in both the files

Is there any way to specify to say the order check only in the file which is being executed at present?

Comment: Is the same code in each test file? What command are you using, and can you include the output of that command?

Comment: test case names differer I make sure that there is no duplicate test case method name , just duplicate order number is there in both the test case files. I run using command "py.test test_* -vv"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Here I started to use [pytest-order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) instead of [pytest-ordering](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-ordering/) because `pytest-ordering` is no longer maintained.

Change all markers from `run` to `order`, for example from `@pytest.mark.run(order=1)` to `@pytest.mark.order(1)`.

Now execute the tests with the following command:

```
pytest -v --order-scope=module
```

The tests will now be ordered in each file independently.

**Reference**: https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/dev/configuration.html#order-scope

Answer (score 1):

I see this issue even when there are two classes in a file and we have defined orders for the functions in both classes.

Example:

```
class Test_abc:

    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_func_a(self):
        print 'class 1 test 1'
    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_func_b(self):
        print 'class 1 test 2'
    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_func_c(self):
        print 'class 1 test 3'

class Test_bcd:

    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_func_ab(self):
        print 'class 2 test 1'
    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_func_bc(self):
        print 'class 2 test 2'
    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_func_cd(self):
        print 'class 2 test 3'
```

Output is like:

```
class 1 test 1
class 2 test 1
class 1 test 2
class 2 test 1
class 1 test 3
class 2 test 1
```

I did something like this to solve this issue

```
@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
class Test_abc:
    def test_func_a(self):
        print 'class 1 test 1'
    def test_func_b(self):
        print 'class 1 test 2'
    def test_func_c(self):
        print 'class 1 test 3'


@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
class Test_bcd:

    def test_func_ab(self):
        print 'class 2 test 1'

    def test_func_bc(self):
        print 'class 2 test 2'

    def test_func_cd(self):
        print 'class 2 test 3'
```

Output:

```
class 1 test 1
class 1 test 2
class 1 test 3
class 2 test 1
class 2 test 2
class 2 test 3
```

So, coming to your issue i think you can try something like this. I know this is not the perfect answer for your question but you can improvise with this solution.
I tried doing this with files (and file names). It seems like the pytest compiler is programmed either to take numbers or alphabets in order. So you may need to name your files like `test_1_foo.py` and `test_2_bar.py` or `test_a.py` and `test_b.py` to execute them in order.
But personally i feel the first way is better.

Comment: You are a life saver. the solution is helped me however when you didn't add method level order, you will get an order problem at the method level. My suggestion is, the order should start from class level, it should continue till end method.